# Next.js 13 navigation router refresh preserves state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this below component and it's included withing a Server Component that fetches data and render it. As it can be seen I call `router.refresh()` on click so it will rerun that page and refetch the data. And it does but the problem is Nextjs keep preserving this state, so when i call `setRefreshing(true)` even though server component rerun refreshing state is still true.

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import Button from './Button'

export default function Refresh() {
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleClick = () => {
    setRefreshing(true)
    router.refresh()
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>
      <i className={`bi bi-arrow-repeat text-lg ${refreshing ? 'animate-spin' : ''}`}></i> 
      Refresh
    </Button>
  )
}
```

`useEffect` is also not running after refresh so i can't set it to false in there either. I've found a workaround to pass an array prop to the component which then it will rerun `useEffect(() => {...}, [serverHackyProp])`.

```
<Refresh inProgress={[false]} />


const [[refreshing], setRefreshing] = useState(inProgress)
const router = useRouter()

useEffect(() => {
  setRefreshing(inProgress)
}, [inProgress])

const handleClick = () => {
  setRefreshing([true])
  router.refresh()
}
```

It works because passed array will always have a new reference so useEffect will run every time server rerun. But I don't like to do that unless it's my last choice but i couldn't find a way to `setRefreshing(false)` after router refreshed (server refetched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trivial solution to this problem is to have your data fetching function return some random value as part of the response, and use that random value as a key of your `Refresh` component. This way your `Refresh` component will be teared down and re-created every time server-side data is refreshed.

```js
// setting revalidate to 0 just for the testing purpose
export const revalidate = 0;

async function getData() {
  return { data: ..., sid: Math.random() };
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <>
      <Refresh key={data.sid} />
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just came back here to reply that I figured this out :) `<Refresh key={Math.random()} />` does the trick when you don't have a unique value that changes over refreshes.

Comment: That’s assuming your parent component doesn’t re-render mid flight.